# How can I re-access a bash console in a Docker?

Tags: docker, console

Im starting some python scripts on a DGX Server running a Nvidia Tensorflow docker. I've managed once to re enter the docker file, where I could see that the process was still running. However I couldn't see the new prints in the console anymore.

Is there a way I can run the docker e.g. a whole night and when I re enter it I can see my complete printed logs in the bash console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are wanting logging. I have only done application logging but maybe this will help: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/

```
$ docker logs [OPTIONS] CONTAINER
```

edit: Additional links:

[log.rowanto.com/docker-console-logs-problem](http://:%20log.rowanto.com/docker-console-logs-problem%20docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging)

[docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging](http://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging)

Comment: Cool that helps! However, I'd be nice if the console stays open anyway. Is there no way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you want the console from where you started the docker container to stay open and display the logs? eg. docker run {image}

Comment: Well yes, it is the same console. I have to connect to the server by ssh. Then I start my docker, and run my python script. When the SSH closes I can get back in the docker, but I can't "re-enter" my console.

Comment: I don't know how to handle this through SSH. Some helpful links might be: https://log.rowanto.com/docker-console-logs-problem/ https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/

Comment: Thank you very much! I guess I'll do it that way :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ docker attach [CONTAINER ID]
```

did the job to re-enter my console over ssh. However as Clayton Harbich pointed out

```
$ docker logs [OPTIONS] CONTAINER ID
```

is what I needed without knowing. Re-entering the console with attach doesn't show the history of console entries. So with those two commands I was able to see what happened and can further observe the scripts process.